# Swift : enum classes does not cast to type "AnyClass"

Tags: swift, class, casting

A user can have several user options for my app:

```
enum OptionAvailable : String {
    case NOTE_GENDER = "note_gender"
    case NOTE_AGEMIN = "note_agemin"
    case NOTE_AGEMAX = "note_agemax"
    case NOTE_ORGA   = "note_orga"
    case NOTE_DMAX   = "note_dmax"
}
```

And each option is associated to a type. To make the association, i did this array :

```
static let typeForOption:[OptionAvailable:AnyClass] = [

    .NOTE_GENDER : MemberOptions.OptGenderToGrade.self, (ERROR)
    .NOTE_AGEMAX : Int.self,
    .NOTE_AGEMIN : Int.self,
    .NOTE_ORGA   : MemberOptions.GradeFrom.self,
    .NOTE_DMAX   : Int.self

]
```

Then when the user will set an option in the option menu, my app will launch a request to my API by calling a function :

```
static func ApiSetOption(
    opt:MemberOptions.OptionAvailable,
    val:Any,
    completionHandler:(()->Void)? = nil,
    errorHandler:((Int,String)->Void)? = nil) throws
{
    // this is in pseudo code, just to see whats going on :

    if val is not of type typeForOption[opt] {
        throw WrongTypeError 
    }
    if typeForOption[opt] is not convertible to String {
        throw TypeNotStringifiable 
    } 
    URLRequest(.POST, "mydomain.com/set/option/\(opt.rawValue)", 
            withBody:val )

}
```

**Problem : I get an error from Swift at (ERROR) : Cannot convert value of type 'MemberOptions.OptGenderToGrade.Type' to expected dictionary value type 'AnyObject.Type'**

Here is MemberOptions.OptGenderToGrade class :

```
enum OptGenderToGrade : String  {
    case MALE = "male"
    case FEMALE = "female"
    case BOTH = "both"

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have

```
static let typeForOption:[OptionAvailable:AnyClass] = [
```

AnyClass means any class. But your types are not class types.

Comment: MemberOptions.OptGenderToGrade.self is not a class ? So an enum is not a class in Swift ? (I just put MemberOptions.OptGenderToGrade code in the post)

Comment: That’s right. A class is a class. An enum is an enum. A struct is a struct.

Comment: How to say the type "AnyEnum" in swift ? Any would reprensent a value of any type, but what I want here is a type that represent "any Enum"

Comment: What you are doing is inadvisable. Swift does not deal in metatypes. You asked about the error. I explained it.

Comment: I'm new to Swift, do you know what would be a better way ? Maybe to express my types as String instead of direct enum names ?

Comment: Your ultimate purpose is opaque to me.